# How to tile a pattern in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, tiles

I have joined two same sized rounded rectangles creating 90 degrees. Then I made 45 degrees guide and copied figure so they both can be on the same guide.

[image]

Then using a blend tool I evenly distributed figures every 9mm.The result I copied and pasted every 24 mm. The result is on the Figure 2:
[image]

Now I want to crop it and save as a pattern. But before that I did Object > Expand ang grouped it to prepare it for cropping. As on the previous stage it wouldn't crop at all. I'm not sure how to do it right so I created a square and placed it in the centre of the group.

[image]

After cropping I've got some weird lines on the shapes. Also my pattern does not tile smoothly. Here is the result: 
[image]

Why do I have these thin lines on rounded rectangles? And more importantly, how can I make this pattern tile smoothly?

**EDIT:** Well, at least one problem is solved. Turned off the Anti-aliased Artwork option and those lines dissapeared.

**EDIT:** I saved pattern from the Figure 2 as a Pattern and tried to tile it by playing with Pattern Options. Now it's much better, but still it doesn't look smooth. Do I need to change something?
[image]

Comment: If you look at the square you've placed at the center of the group you should be able to see that it would not line up properly once tiled.

Comment: @Johannes, I saw that. I don't know how to place it properly.

Comment: Start here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/create-edit-patterns.html You shouldn't need to "crop" anything.

Comment: @Scott, thank you, I read it and made my pattern different way. It looks better but still it does not tile smoothly. Am I on the right track? What do I need to change?

Comment: Unfortunately, I see this is *exceptionally* localized. Meaning an answer to help correct *this* pattern wouldn't *really* be that useful for anyone else, unless they were attempting the same pattern. You realize you could probably [download a free pattern](http://wegraphics.net/downloads/50-free-herringbone-illustrator-pattern-swatches/) and change colors, right?

Comment: @Scott, as you said the answer might be usefull for someone else. Moreover, correcting this pattern will give me an experience that will help to make better patterns in the future. If I wanted to download a free pattern I wouldn't try so hard to finish this one. Please help me to finish it.

Comment: I think you misread... "**wouldn't** really be that useful for anyone else"

Answer (score 2):

**The base module:**

[image: base]

**The composition:**

[image: modules]

**Finding the horizontal and vertical repetition**:

[image: MODULE]

**The Pattern Frame**:

[image: frame]

**The Module**:

- Expand the strokes
- Select all and using the **Shape Builder Tool** and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, delete every part of shape outside the frame

[image: pattern]

**New Pattern**:

The pattern is done, but the gradients from the sides shapes must be fixed

[image: pattern]

**Fixing the gradients**:

From the **Pattern Editor** and using the **Gradient Annotator**

[image: fixing the gradients]

**Result**:

[image: pattern filling]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute to another method:

1- Make just one module.

2- Rotate it to 45 degrees and drag it to Swathes panel.

3- Size the tile to the desired size and position.

4- Apply the pattern to the object.

5- Rotate just the pattern in -45 degrees.

See the image below for references.

[image]

Comment: Note: I am using the same dimension that @Danielillo used.